# Can't obtain values using sscanf

Tags: c

I am trying to get input from a text file which includes the following line

```
John,.) 789.. 89,88,79,69
```

However, I am unable to obtain the numbers correctly with my sscanf statement, where am I going wrong? The name is printed correctly but the marks are garbage values...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char name[20];
    int ID;
    int marks[4];

} details;

int main()
{
    char string[100];
    details student[2];

    FILE *ptr = fopen("testing7.txt", "r");
    if ((ptr = fopen ("testing7.txt", "r")) != NULL)
        printf("file successfully opened\n");
    else
    {
        printf("file could not be opened\n");
        return 0;
    }

    fgets(string,100, ptr);

    // testing to see if string was obtained
    printf("%s", string);

    sscanf(string,"%s,.) %d.. %d,%d,%d,%d", student[0].name, &student[0].ID,   &student[0].marks[0], &student[0].marks[1],&student[0].marks[2],&student[0].marks[3]);

    printf("%s\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", student[0].name, student[0].ID, student[0].marks[0],  student[0].marks[1],  student[0].marks[2],  student[0].marks[3]);

    fclose(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY can u look into this and see if u can do something about it

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: i dont think its that long to indent..

Comment: You should **always** indent your code. This is good habit. Also I think it is long enough to be hard to read (at least for me).

Comment: can some1 give me the correct sscanf statement

Comment: i think its clearer @Nabla

Comment: "Indent" means inserting tabs before the code lines, such that the number of tabs indicates the bracket depth. You didn't do that. Also concerning your problem you should carefully read http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma, the fullstop or the bracket are not considered whitespace characters so the format  format specifier `%s` will consume them.

I haven't tested this, but the following format string should work for your case:

`%[^,],.) %d.. %d,%d,%d,%d`

Explanation:

`%[^,]` => Read until a comma is encountered.

Comment: @user3151918 Please accept the answer when stack overflow lets you. Thanks.